A false proof of Dini theorem
I consider $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ the space of continuous functions from a compact metric space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the supremum norm. I would like to prove Dino’s theorem

Let $(f_n)_n\subset C(X,\mathbb{R})$ be an increasing sequence of functions that converges pointwise to $f$ with $f$ continuous. Then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Here is my attempt that should be false because I do not use the fact the sequence is increasing :
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and define $A_{n,\varepsilon}=\{x\in X : \lvert f(x) -f_n(x)\rvert<\varepsilon\}$. We have that $A_{n,\varepsilon}$ is open as the pre image of $[0,\varepsilon)$ (open in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$) by $g=\lvert f-f_n\rvert$ and $g$ is continuous. Let $x\in X$, we have by pointwise convergence the existence of an integer $N(x)$ such that $\lvert f(x)-f_{N(x)}(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$ such that $x\in A_{N(x),\varepsilon}$ so $X=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n,\varepsilon}$. Since $X$ is compact, there exists a finite open cover $A_{i_1,\varepsilon},…, A_{i_k,\varepsilon}$. Let $N=\max(i_1,…,i_k)$, then for all $n\geq N$ we have that $\sup_{x\in X}\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$.
Do you see where is the mistake please ?

Edit
Mistake found I think : in the definition of $A_{n,\varepsilon}$, the $n$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$ and is by no mean related to the very definition of pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)$ to $f(x)$. Hence, it is possible that by taking a rank $N$ we have $\lvert f_N(x)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$, and then at rank $N+1$ we have that $\lvert f_{N+1}(x)-f(x)\rvert>\varepsilon$.

How do you know there is a mistake?

@ArielFishbein: I'm not OP, but it is very easy to construct examples of non-monotone sequences of functions that converge to a continuous functions over a compact set, and the convergence is not uniform.

@ArielFishbein  I do not use all the hypothesis

@MartinArgerami I haven't even read his "proof" I just thought that if he knew why there was a mistake, maybe it'd be easier for him to understand where is it, and why is it.

The mistake, as most often happens, it's in the part of the proof where you gloss over stuff. The problem is in the last sentence: you cannot guarantee that if $N>i_k$, then $A_{N,\epsilon}\subset A_{i_k,\epsilon}$. That's precisely where one uses monotonicity in the proof.

I think it is exactly what I tried to say in my edit (if you want to read it) ! Thank you a lot !

Yes indeed! Glad I could help.
